# How do I make jQuery smoothly scroll to a constantly-changing position?

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make an image slider, drawing inspiration from [this site](http://www.medianovak.com/).

I've gotten it working, but I can't figure out how to make it smoothly slide between positions; If I just use a jQuery .animate(), then it jerks around randomly, presumably trying to play catch-up with the queued X positions.

How do I smoothly slide between points on the slider?

[JSFiddle Version](http://jsfiddle.net/ENhwT/39/)

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/80">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/80">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/80">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/80">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/80">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/80">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/80">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/80">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/80">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/80">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/80">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/80">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/80">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/80">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/80">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/80">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/80">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slider{
    width: 550px;
    height:134px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#slider img {
    border: 1px Solid #282828;
    margin: 16px 6px 16px 10px;
    padding:0;
}
#slider img:hover{
    border: 1px Solid #eee;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#slider").mousemove(function(e) {
    var sidePadding = 50;
    var parentOffset = $(this).offset(); 
    var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    var scrollX = ((relX - sidePadding)  / ($(this).width() + sidePadding)) * ($(this).prop('scrollWidth'));

    $(this).scrollLeft(scrollX);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to add `position: relative;`to the images, and replace scrollLeft() with `$(this).children().stop().animate({ left: (-1*scrollX) + 'px' }, 600, 'swing');`

You'd have to remove the browser scrollbar too, but that should be easy by setting `overflow: hidden;` on the parent div.

http://jsfiddle.net/ENhwT/41/

Answer (score 0):

Use flex slider for smoother scrolling. Add `move:1` in the function of the flex slider.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  SyntaxHighlighter.all();
});

$(window).load(function(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: true,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    minItems: 5,
    smoothHeight: false, 
    move:1,
    start: function(slider){
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    }
  });
});
```